# Swift 3: Cannot call value of non-function type '(() -> Void)?'

Tags: swift, swift3, scntranscaction

This function worked before the curse of all curses, also known as Swift 3. After migrating to Swift 3, Xcode, my friendly and cuddly IDE, displays this frustrating error against the line `SCNTransaction.completionBlock`:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '(() -> Void)?'

Several other posts deal with similar errors, but none of those solutions apply.

What is wrong with the line???

```
func test(_ block: SCNNode, animated: Bool) {
    // Do stuff
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = animated ? AnimationDur : 0.0
    SCNTransaction.completionBlock {
        block.removeFromParentNode()
    }
    // Animate stuff
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[SCNTransaction.completionBlock](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scntransaction/1644116-completionblock) is a class property. Perhaps you mean this?

```
//                             ↓
SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
    block.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! Frustrating how much changed in Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

`SCNTransaction.completionBlock` isn't a function you can call via trailing closure syntax, it's a property. You'll need to assign the closure to it:

```
SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
    block.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

In other words, you just need to add an equal sign.

Comment: Sorry, kennytm beat you to the answer but upvoted nonetheless :)

Comment: Missed it by 8 seconds :)

Comment: Sorry, but since you seem like you're a Swift 3 expert, I'll post another one for you. :)

Comment: Here's the q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630247/swift-3-cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutabledictionary-to-expected-argument. Thanks if you can help!