# Swift 3: Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]!'

Tags: swift, swift3

This code worked before Swift 3. (Curse you Swift 3!)

Now it's showing this error against the `Flurry.logEvent(eventName, withParameters: userData!)` line:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected
>   argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]!'

Casting `userData!` to `[AnyHashable : Any]` produces this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to type
>   '[AnyHashable : Any]' in coercion

```
func logEvent(_ eventName: String, userData: NSMutableDictionary?) {
    // Use <userData> or create new one?
    var userData = userData
    if userData == nil {
        userData = NSMutableDictionary()
    }

    // Set base properties
    userData!.setObject(gUser.tofus.count, forKey: "Num Tofus" as NSCopying)
    userData!.setObject(gUser.getLifetimeTofus(), forKey: "Num Lifetime Tofus" as NSCopying)

    // Call Flurry
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Flurry.logEvent(eventName, withParameters: userData! as [AnyHashable:Any])
    }
}
```

What's the right syntax for Swift 3?

Comment: `Flurry.logEvent` expects `[AnyHashable:Any]`? Can you show the full method definition?

Comment: I am going to share this answer with you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561539/cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutabledictionary-to-type-nsobject-anyobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561539/cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutabledictionary-to-type-nsobject-anyobject)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If that `Flurry.logEvent(_:withParameters:)` takes `[AnyHashable: Any]`, why don't you use it as your local `userData`?

```
func logEvent(_ eventName: String, userData: NSMutableDictionary?) {
    // Use <userData> or create new one?
    var userData = userData as NSDictionary? as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [:]
    
    // Set base properties
    userData["Num Tofus"] = gUser.tofus.count
    userData["Num Lifetime Tofus"] = gUser.getLifetimeTofus()
    
    // Call Flurry
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Flurry.logEvent(eventName, withParameters: userData)
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Xcode 8.1 GM seed including [SE-0139](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md) and [SE-0140](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md) is out, so the list below is updated.

These are the **Objective-C safe** types, when set to a `[AnyHashable: Any]` dictionary (or set in a `[Any]` array, or simply passed to `Any` which is a non-null `id` in Objective-C) in which is passed to Objective-C world:

### Swift 3.0.1/Xcode 8.1

- Optional values including `nil`

`nil` is converted to `NSNull`, all non-nil Optionals are unwrapped.

*(`NSNull` may not be what you want. Still be careful about nil-checking.)*

- **All** numeric types and `Bool`

`Int8`, `UInt8`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, `UInt64`, as well as
`Int`, `UInt`, `Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat` and `Bool`. These are converted to `NSNumber`.

- `String`

Converted to `NSString`.

- `Array`, where `Element` is Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSArray`.

- `Dictionary`, where `Key` and `Value` are Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSDictionary`.

- `Set`, where `Element` is Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSSet`

- `NSObject` descendent types

Not converted, used as is.

- Value types which have counter-part reference types

See the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID211).

- Value types where `NSValue` has an initializer for

`NSRange`,
`CGPoint`,
`CGVector`,
`CGSize`,
`CGRect`,
`CGAffineTransform`,
`UIEdgeInsets`,
`UIOffset`,
`CATransform3D`,
`CMTime`,
`CMTimeRange`,
`CMTimeMapping`,
`CLLocationCoordinate2D`,
`MKCoordinateSpan`,
`SCNVector3`,
`SCNVector4`,
`SCNMatrix4`.
These types are converted to `NSValue`. *(`NSRange` was already convertible to `NSValue` in older Swifts, but not well-documented.)*

### Bad things (example)

Still some values may be converted to `_SwiftValue` even in Swift 3.0.1.

- Swift only types such as (Swift-only)enum, struct, tuple...

(See [this list](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53).)

I haven't checked all wrapper enums and structs, but some of them (for example, `Notification.Name` to `NSString`) seem to be safely converted.

---

## Swift 3.0.0/Xcode 8.0

- Non-Optional numeric types and `Bool`

`Int`, `UInt`, `Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat` and `Bool`. These are converted to `NSNumber`.

- Non-Optional `String`

Converted to `NSString`.

- Non-Optional `Array`, where `Element` is Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSArray`.

- Non-Optional `Dictionary`, where `Key` and `Value` are Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSDictionary`.

- Non-Optional `Set`, where `Element` is Objective-C safe

Converted to `NSSet`

- Non-Optional `NSObject` descendent types

Not converted, used as is.

- Non-Optional value types which have counter-part reference types

See the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID211). (The linked article is updated for Swift 3.0.1.)

### Bad things (example)

These may be converted to `_SwiftValue`, which is completely useless and disastrous in Objective-C world.

- `Int8`, `UInt8`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, `UInt64`
- Any Optional values including `nil`
- Swift only types such as (Swift-only)enum, struct, tuple...

Comment: Oh this is much cleaner!

Comment: But why the [:] as the second operand?

Comment: @Crashalot, using nil-coalescing operator `??` is a concise way to give a default value for nil case. `?? [:]` in my code corresponds to your `if userData == nil {userData = NSMutableDictionary()}`.

Comment: Right, so shouldn't both operands be [AnyHashable:Any]?

Comment: @Crashalot, yes, but the right hand side `[:]` is a literal, so Swift can easily infer and define the type as ` [AnyHashable:Any]`.

Comment: Oh interesting ... so if you had [NSObject:AnyObject] as the left operand, [:] would get inferred as [NSObject:AnyObject]?

Comment: @Crashalot, you need to know one bad thing with using `[AnyHashable: Any]`. `Any` can literally consumes Any Swift types. If you mistakenly pass something which cannot be handled in Objective-C world, that something would cause disastrous effect. Use it with care, please.

Comment: What are examples of things not handled in Obj-C world?

Comment: @Crashalot, that can be some amount. I'll update my answer.